# Unity 2018.3 android dex merging issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Before you decide to dismiss this post as "duplicate" without even reading it, understand that I have looked at a TON of posts related to this topic and I can't find a solution for my instance, including all of the ones that StackOverflow suggested. Most of the posts are for Android Studio instead of unity.

My error is given in Unity when trying to build to android, it crashes here.

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.6.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleDebug"

stderr[
D8: Program type already present: com.unity3d.ads.BuildConfig

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
```

I've tried changing stuff with a build.gradle file like a lot of posts suggest, but I can't get anything to work.

The error didn't exist in Unity 2018.2. I checked right before I updated, but the update is now throwing this issue.

Does anyone have any UNITY specific ideas what to do here? I've tried so many things and nobody's post has been able to help me yet.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This applies 2019.1.0b7 also. Removing Advertisements as in the answer below allowed it to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error probably happens when you add a library which is not compatible with your compileSdkVersion.
In your case you can have libs that were not imported by default by unity (and now are)
or there can be a problem with the Build Tools version. (You can try updating them)

I had similar problem a few versions ago, but I don't remember how I fixed it.
I didn't have time to upgrade to unity 2018.3 yet. (So the tips are more like guesses, but it may help you solve the issue.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I appreciate it and will look into it - I will post if i find a solution

Comment: Apparently the google ads mediation was what was throwing the error. Once removed, the error went away. Not sure what i'll do to work around it later but at least it compiles again. Thanks for the advice

Comment: It may be related to this: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/08/07/unity-releases-google-advertising-for-developers/ All of the ads will be served by unity ads and monetized by unity or google.(Payout thorough unity) Maybe they also dropped AdMob, but I'm not familiar with the topic so I may be wrong.

Comment: Maybe Google dropped AdMob for Unity as Google is now another advertising partner within Unity’s unified auction

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you're saying using Unity Ads alone will essentially be able to pull google ads through their network too? So Unity Ads is the superior option in that case?

Comment: I'm also confused by the  article, but it seems so.However without any testing I cannot be sure.

Comment: Hey. I switched from internal deprecated build, to modern gradle build, and now i am seeing this error. It is super frustrating, since I am not able to build. I'm not using google ads, but unity ads. 1) how did you find out which dependencies were incompatible with the SDK ? 2) how do you update a dependency? Unity was very keen on which version of NDK i had to download, why can it not run with the latest version that SDK manager downloaded. This is extremly weird and confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You can open the PackageManage under Window in the menu bar and remove Advertisement or you can delete the com.unity.ads file of Library/PackageCache in the project directory to resolve this issue.

Comment: That was the issue. Fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My settings (Mac):
- Android Studio 2.3
- Unity 2019.1.5f1:
- Player Settings -> Other Settings –> Scripting Runtime Version = .Net 4
- Package Manager -> Advertisement: Uninstalled
- Preferences -> External Tools -> Android: checked Installed with Unity (everything)

My solution:
- delete GoogleMobileAds from project
- delete PlayServicesResolver from project
- delete Plugins from project
- Import Package -> Custom Package -> GoogleMobileAds.unitypackage (3.15.1 in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Dex Errors generally occur when you have too many methods imported in a project, not because of a specific package. I assume upgrading to new version made you import new stuff to your project.

You need to enable ProGuard.

Cause: http://twinkfed.homedns.org/Android///tools/building/multidex.html

Fix: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va0FQNlBUX0